# How to @SQLDelete, soft delete, entity with a composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

how to obtain pieces of composite key in `@SQLDelete` to perform soft deletion of an entity?

```
@Data
class DummyKey {
    private Long foo;
    private Long bar;
}


@IdClass(DummyKey.class)
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE dummy SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE ???") //how to get key params
@Where(clause = "deleted='N'")
class Dummy {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo")
    private Long foo;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "bar")
    private Long bar;

    @Column(name = "stuff")
    private String stuff;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private String deleted;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values of the composite ID are bound to the prepared statement in the order of the properties of the `IdClass`, so this should work:

`@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE dummy SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE foo=? AND bar=?")`

(The [`AbstractEntityPersister`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/c3f8e56f28886918c2f41e9eea80f0f311ca9173/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.java#L3673) delegates the binding to the identifier type, so in this case to [`ComponentType`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/c3f8e56f28886918c2f41e9eea80f0f311ca9173/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/ComponentType.java#L337) which iterates over the properties with help of an [`AbstractComponentTuplizer`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/c3f8e56f28886918c2f41e9eea80f0f311ca9173/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tuple/component/AbstractComponentTuplizer.java#L25))

Comment: In general, it works! However I don't know why but the properties are listed in different order than they are declared in key class - feels like it is... alphabetic? Anyway the ordering is consistent so it's good enough for me, thanks!